# Cannot use qsub: unable to send message to qmaster using port 6444

Tags: parallels

After some updates and upgrades on 16.04, I can't use qsub from gridengine to run parallel jobs, it said:

```
unable to send message to qmaster using port 6444
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem? As far as I know, I need to open port 6444 to allow qsub runs.

Comment: Are the sge daemons running? Check with `ps aux | grep sge`.

Comment: This is the output, `user 15355  0.0  0.0  15244   936 pts/16   S+   17:16   0:00 grep --color=auto sge`

Comment: So the daemon is not running. Use `/etc/init.d/gridengine-master restart` and `/etc/init.d/gridengine-exec` to restart the processes. On the nodes you only need the `gridengine-exec`.